# Excel 2007 formula to find out date from year and week number?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to make my work hour notekeeping a bit easier. I note my hours by project so that Monday - Friday are in their own columns. I report my hours based on this weekly, so each worksheet has one week.

Now, I'd like the Mon-Fri columns have the short date ("2.10." for today for example) in addition of the day name without manually changing them each week. I have the year and week numbers in their own cells. Can one get dates with those?

Comment: Lines. If A1 Says "Mon", then hours in Monday will be A2..A20.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit unclear. So, A1 has the text "Mon". A2 has project X hours for that day, A3 has project Z hoursand so on. B1 is "Tue", B2..B20 hours for Tuesday and so on. Week number and year placing do not really matter, but lets say they are in F1 and G1, respectively.

Comment: That would work, thanks. I'd still like to know if the date calculation would be possible :)

Comment: To reference a column that has the year and week and then return M-F? How is the year/week formatted?

Comment: At this time they are just informal, so they are General.

Comment: I've provided a formula in my answer that performs this function starting with the actual date and then going to Year/Week. Can you work it backwards like that?

Comment: Possibly, I'll have to dig own to it when I have a bit more time. Thanks! :)

Comment: If it doesn't work, come back and let us know what format your year/week is in - like is it YYYY W, YY W, YY WW, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the first date, right click the bottom-right corner of the cell and drag it down. Then select "fill weekdays".

[image]

Then right click, go to format and put in a custom format of `ddd mm.dd` or whatever you want

[image]

If you do this first, you can use the `=WEEKNUM()` formula to get the week number of the dates and drag that down. `=WEEKNUM(C1,2)`. You can also use `YEAR()` to get the year. So you could do -

```
D1=YEAR(C1)&"-"&WEEKNUM(C1,2)
```

To get something like `2014-2`

[image]

Comment: Based on your formula and some google-fu, I found the formula from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847678/calculate-the-month-from-the-year-and-week-number-in-excel/10855872#10855872

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I didn't know about the Fill Weekdays option. Helpful!